# Nested [DataContract]'s not serialising through WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, datacontractserializer, datacontract

I'm having an issue where a class decorated with the `[DataContract]` attribute and appropriate `[DataMember]` attributes on properties is not serialising nested `[DataContract]` classes.

This is the class i'm trying to serialise:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://foo.bar.com.au")]
[KnownType(typeof(Point))]
[KnownType(typeof(Site))]
public sealed class Alarm : IExtensibleDataObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public Point SourcePoint { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Site SourceSite { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime ActiveTime { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsAcknowledged { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Response { get; set; }

    private ExtensionDataObject _ExtensionData;
    public ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
    {
        get { return _ExtensionData; }
        set { _ExtensionData = value; }
    }
}
```

This is being sent via a WCF service being hosted in an .NET 4.0 IIS site.

My issue is that for some reason, the `SourcePoint` and `SourceSite` properties are not being serialised. They are just returning null. Oddly, the ExtensionData contains all the fields of those two classes.

The other strange thing, is that when I run the IIS host locally on the dev web server, they are correctly serialised. The only change between the two tests is that the endpoint in the test client is pointing to the different IIS hosts.

Anyone have any idea's what's happening here?

EDIT: Added Site & Point snippets

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://foo.bar.com.au")]
public sealed class Site : BaseObject
{
    //~Site Details
    [DataMember]
    public string GisAssetId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Catchment { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Location { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string MelwaysReference { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And the Point class.

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://foo.bar.com.au")]
public class Point : BaseObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public object CurrentValue { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CurrentValueFormatted { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsDigital { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Source { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool InService { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsAlarmEnabled { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double TrendMinimum { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double TrendMaximum { get; set; }
}
```

It should be noted that BaseObject is a base class that has the same DataContract signature as the rest.

Comment: What do Site and Point look like? If I had to blind guess: is te production server running the same version of .NET? The behaviour of types not decorated as contracts changed in one of the service packs

Comment: Snippets of Site & Point. I can confirm that they both serialise correctly as I have other WCF methods that request lists of Site and Points and they are being returned correctly.

Comment: Since you don't have any ignores or other things like that, have you tried removing all the Datacontract/datamember tags? None of them are strictly required in 3.5 or 4.0. If they're not there and you have a service return a class, WCF implies it. I've got an entire system where only two classes are decorated: one of them is a MessageContract, and the other has some IgnoreDataMembers. Everything else works on its own. :)  (You also shouldn't need the KnownType's on Alarm either way.)

Comment: I managed to work out what the issue was. Thanks for your help!

Comment: after this was solved, it works as a good example of how to nest data contracts. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the Visual Studio Web Setup project, that was being used to deploy to the server, wasn't updating the dependencies of the IIS host properly.

This means that any changes to the data contracts were not being copied across, causing the issues as the server didn't know about the properties to serialise them.

I had to remove the project output from the setup project and re-add it before it would pick up the dependencies properly.

Now everything works again!