# Which must be used with XmlSerializer and WCF - DataContract or MessageContract?

Tags: c#, wcf, xml-serialization

I need to write WCF service wich will take **.xml** file deserialize it into my custom calss and then do some operations on that data. I have written test version of this application which use console but not WCF. Here is how my code looks like:

```
[Serializable]
public class ErrorMsgElement
{
    [XmlElement("Sender")]
    public string SenderOfMessage{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement()]
    public Int64 UserID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement()]
    public Int64 SerialNumber { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("DateTime")]
    public DateTime DateAndTimeOfMessage { get; set; }
}


[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Root")]
public class ErrorMessage
{
    [XmlElement("Header")]
    public string HeaderOfFile { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ErrorMsg")]
    public ErrorMsgElement msgElent { get; set; }
}
```

**And Main code**

```
        ErrorMessage myErrorMsg = new ErrorMessage();
        //pathToFile is original path
        string path = @pathToFile;

        XmlSerializer myXmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ErrorMessage));

        using (StreamReader myStrReader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            myErrorMsg = (ErrorMessage)myXmlSerializer.Deserialize(myStrReader);
        }

        //some operations on myErrorMsg such as writing to database
```

It works fine in console application. Now I need to write same logic in WCF service. But I don't know what should I use - **[Serializable]**, **[DataContact]**, **[MessageContract]** or someting else?. Consider that I have some [XmlArray] atributes in my custom classes as well. And if I add [DataContract] atribute to my **ErrorMessage** class do I have to add same attribute to **ErrorMsgElement** as following?

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class ErrorMsgElement
{
    ...
}

[DataContract]
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Root")]
public class ErrorMessage
{
    ...

    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement("ErrorMsg")]
    public ErrorMsgElement msgElent { get; set; }
}
```

All answers are well appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

in wcf `[DataContact]` and `DataContractSerializer` are recommended for what do you want to do. But you can also use `XmlSerializer` as well it's really only your choice(using first or second don't making diffrent for performance of your application).

**Edit:**

When you adding `DataContract` attribute to your class than you don't have to add `Serializable` attribute too the same class `DataContract` is equal to `Serializable`

check this for answer about [nested DataContracts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997997/nested-datacontracts-not-serialising-through-wcf)